# catkin tools stopped working with recent update

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I just updated my focal dist and got a new catkin-tools:

```
Setting up python3-catkin-tools (0.6.1-1)
```

And now I get:

```
tompe@philo:~/lrs_ws/src$ catkin build
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/catkin", line 6, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3254, in <module>
    def _initialize_master_working_set():
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3237, in _call_aside
    f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3266, in _initialize_master_working_set
    working_set = WorkingSet._build_master()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 584, in _build_master
    ws.require(__requires__)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 901, in require
    needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 787, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req, requirers)
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'trollius' distribution was not found and is required by catkin-tools
```

Anybody else seeing this? Is there a workaroundor do I have to use catkin_make?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/360363/catkin-tools-stopped-working-with-recent-update/) by [tompe17](https://answers.ros.org/users/22519/tompe17/) on ROS Answers with karma: 140 on 2020-08-26

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-08-26**:
This is a known issue. See [catkin/catkin_tools#594](https://github.com/catkin/catkin_tools/issues/594) (later comments).

And #q353113 for a possible work-around.

**Comment by [tompe17](https://answers.ros.org/users/22519/tompe17/) on 2020-08-26**:
But it worked before the latest update. So something was broken with the Ubuntu update of catkin-tools.

**Comment by [tompe17](https://answers.ros.org/users/22519/tompe17/) on 2020-08-26**:
I tried the suggested workaround before posting the question and it did not work.

**Comment by [tompe17](https://answers.ros.org/users/22519/tompe17/) on 2020-08-26**:
This is strange. ros2-latest.list containe one line for focal and

deb [arch=amd64,arm64] http://packages.ros.org/ros2/ubuntu bionic main

so I got the wrong version of python3-catkin-tools from bionic. Removing this line and reinstalling the correct version and it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Seems to have been my fault. For some strange reason my ros2-latest.list was:

```
deb [arch=amd64] http://packages.ros.org/ros2/ubuntu focal main
deb [arch=amd64,arm64] http://packages.ros.org/ros2/ubuntu bionic main
```

Removing the bionic line and re-installing python3-catkin-tools fixed the problem. I had gotten a later version from bionic installed which caused the problem.

---

Originally posted by [tompe17](https://answers.ros.org/users/22519/tompe17/) with karma: 140 on 2020-08-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0